# Scrapy and flask on ec2

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, amazon-ec2, scrapy, aws-lambda

So basically im new into this, so bear with me, please.

I have  3 python spiders that uses: scrappy,scrappy-user-agent,pandas,MongoDB.
they scrape around 150-200 pages every 12 hours and store the data locally into MongoDB collections.
And I have a flask app that connects the API endpoints with the collections and returns the data as response.

Would it possible to deploy both to same ec2 instance, or would flask and response be slowed down for users while the scrapping is done in parallel in same machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is *possible* to deploy them both in the same instance. However, you need to know how much memory and CPU your both applications use, and choose your instance type accordingly.

Given the low frequency of your web scraping, it is very possible that it does not take much memory and CPU, but it may be the case if you are doing some heavy processing of the scrapped data.

To know about the memory and CPU configurations of each instance type: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

Comment: And running flask in background while the 3 scrappers starts each after the other won't slow down the response? and can I the machine set it to scale automatically based on the process? or does it have to be fixed?

Comment: EC2 instances are fixed. You can always make an image (a "snapshop") of one of your instances and launch a new instance from that image, with a different instance type. If you want a automatically scaled system, you need to put your flask application in a Elastic Beanstalk environment (https://aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/) and keep your Scrapy spiders in a different ec2 instance. But you can always choose an EC2 instance which is strong enough to hold your 3 scrappers and application, it all depends on how critical is your flask application.

Comment: Aha I see, okay i would stick in that case to ec2 instance and upgrade to another intance if i needed to thanks.
Its an api end points app, partically having 6 endpoints to connect the android/ios app with a backend (the data collected)

Comment: And in that case do i need extra work than deploying, install required packages, set cronjob and figure a way to start flask/spiders/mongodb if the machine was restarted to make the apis work? or am i missing something

Comment: You need to set up your mongodb and your application as daemons in your instance. You can do this with Systemd. Here you have an example: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-gunicorn-and-nginx-on-centos-7

Comment: If my answer was useful please upvote and accept it :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171561/discussion-between-eqperes-and-dude).